# Как установить Docker на Centos 6.10?

Tags: linux, docker, centos, centos6

Выполнил команды по установке Docker на Centos 6:
# yum install epel-release
# yum install docker-io

В терминале пишет докер установился, но когда хочу запустить эти команды
# service docker start
# service docker status
# chkconfig docker on
Пишет unrecognized service

Comment: Для установки докера есть официальная информация как устанавливать. Поищите получше.

Comment: я уже на всех сайтах искал информацию, включая официальную документацию. На Centos 6.10 не хочет работать.

Comment: [To install Docker Engine, you need a maintained version of CentOS 7](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/). это, конечно, не **официальная документация дистрибутива**, но стоит к ней прислушаться: ведь именно с этого сайта вы хотите установить программу docker. а там, согласно процитированному, подходящей версии просто нет.

Comment: Что у вас видно после этого `systemctl --all | grep docker`?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ как установить. Если кому интересно команды прикрепил. Актуально на июль 2020))

```
yum install -y centos-release-xen 
echo includepkgs=kernel kernel-firmware >> /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Xen.repo
yum update -y kernel 
reboot
yum install -y https://get.docker.com/rpm/1.7.0/centos-6/RPMS/x86_64/docker-engine-1.7.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
service docker start  
docker ps
```